How to read a 'CompactSVMModel' save in a .mat file from a C++/Qt program
I tried to save a machine learning model into a .mat file, and then read it from a Qt/C++ application.
Following the documentation, I managed to read files containing basic types like double or int.
As my model is of type 'classreg.learning.classif.CompactClassificationSVM', I wonder if it is still possible to read it.
As and example, i saved this iosnosphere model on matlab
    load ionosphere
    SVMModel = fitcsvm(X,Y,'Standardize',true,'ClassNames',{'b','g'})
    CompactSVMModel = compact(SVMModel)
    save("CompactSVMModel.mat", "CompactSVMModel")

I imported the relevant library in the CMakeLists.txt
    find_package(Matlab "x.xx" EXACT COMPONENTS  "MX_LIBRARY" "MAT_LIBRARY" "DATAARRAY_LIBRARY" )

    target_link_libraries(target PRIVATE Matlab::mat )


I used the "mat.h" library to open and read the data.
    #include "mat.h"


    void readMatFile(const std::string& filepath) {
        std::string stdFilename = filepath + "/CompactSVMModel.mat";
        const char *variableName = "CompactSVMModel";

        // Open the MAT-File
        MATFile *matFile = matOpen(stdFilename.c_str(), "r");
        if (!matFile) {
            qDebug() << "Error opening MAT file: " << stdFilename;
        }

        // Read the variable from the MAT-File
        mxArray *dataArray = matGetVariable(matFile, variableName);
        if (!dataArray) {
            qDebug() << "Error reading variable: " << variableName << " from MAT file: " << stdFilename;
        }
        ...
    }

At the if statement, matFile is NULL.

Are you sure that the file path is valid? How do you get it? What/how calls readMatFile()?

Yes file path is valid, in my tests, filepath is replaced by the actual path inside readMatFile() and not used as an argument. The function is called in the main().

So, if you do something like QFile.exists(<filepath>) (or any similar file access function) it returns true?

Yes, i already had success with reading some list of integer or double.

I someone else encountered the same issue, there is this answer:
https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2139231-how-to-read-a-compactsvmmodel-saved-in-a-mat-file-from-a-c-qt-program
